# Read mq queue errors in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, ibm-mq

I am using amqsput to write a message to a queue in a batch file.

```
call "C:\folderdir\code\mqfile\amqsput" QUEUE QMGR < File
```

The code works fine. However I want to capture the errors and echo appropriate response message.

Ex - if the queue is full, mq will return an error code and message. I want to capture the message and code and print it on screen.

errorlevel doesnt capture the mq error codes.

Comment: How is it returning an error code and message?  Through the output?

Comment: Yeah. it displays on the stdout/err.

Answer (score 0):

#### Capture the output using a `for /f` loop.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('call "C:\folderdir\code\mqfile\amqsput" QUEUE QMGR ^< File 2^>^&1') do echo(%%A
pause
```

`2>&1` is redirecting the stderr into the stdout and the `for /f` loop is capturing the stdout.

#### Example / Proof of Concept

Test.bat

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('call Test2.bat ^< Test.txt 2^>^&1') do echo(Test = %%A
pause
exit /b 0
```

Test2.bat

```
@echo off
set /p "Test="
echo(%Test%
echo Error 1>&2
exit /b 0
```

Test.txt

```
Hello
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>Test.bat
Test = Hello
Test = Error
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Will test it and let you know. Thanks!